# Highlight text using <mark> on React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a real-time text highlighter with React, right now this is the code that I got so far and it was inspired on a solution using innerHTML and it doesn't works.

```
const Highlighter = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const getInput = (input) => {
    setData(input.target.value);
  };
  const textoToSearch = (input) => {
    setSearch(input.target.value);
    search.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
    let pattern = new RegExp(`${search}`, "gi");
    let teste = data.replace(pattern, (match) => `<mark>${match}</mark>`);
    console.log(teste)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea data-testid="source-text" onChange={getInput} />
      <input
        className="search"
        data-testid="search-term"
        onChange={textoToSearch}
      />
      <p>
        case sentitive?
        <input type="checkbox" data-testid="case-sensitive" />
      </p>
      <div data-testid="result">{data}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Highlighter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/). Install mark.js npm package.

Then the below code will do for you.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Mark from "mark.js";

export default function App() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchterm] = useState("");
  const markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector("#search-node"));

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchterm(event.target.value);
    markInstance.unmark({
      done: () => {
        markInstance.mark(event.target.value);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="start typing here"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleSearch}
      />
      <div id="search-node">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
          nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
          sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
          rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is an example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cloud-dz3i6v?file=/src/App.js)

[image: Sample Screenshot]